# How can I add my method inside java stream?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream that outputs a set:

```
1=[15.01.2021, 30.09.2012]
2=[12.05.2021, 02.01.2021]
3=[14.02.2021]
4=[11.05.2022]

private static void groupDateById (Collection <Logs> firstFileLog, Collection <Logs> second) {
    Stream.of (firstFileLog, second)
        .flatMap (Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Logs::getId, Collectors.mapping(Logs::getTime,Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

I also have a method that checks the difference between dates. Between the first and the second.

```
// Displays the difference. In this case, one month.
GFG.findDifference("2020-09-12", "2020-10-12");
```

Is it possible to add this method of calculating the date difference to the stream? To immediately calculate for all dates.

I need to get this output

```
1=[15.01.2021, 30.09.2012], difference(second date - first) 99 month
2=[12.05.2021, 02.01.2021], difference(second date - first)..
3=[14.02.2021] - ignore
4=[11.05.2022] - ignore
```

Comment: Streams are not a very good fit for operations that cannot process elements separately.

Comment: Can you show the output that you expect to get?

Comment: I want this output data 
1=[15.01.2021, 30.09.2012] difference (date2-date1)
2=[12.05.2021, 02.01.2021] difference (date2-date1)
3=[14.02.2021] - ignore
4=[11.05.2022] - ignore

Comment: @Taras What if there are more than two dates in the list? Should the output contain the difference between every consecutive date?

Comment: @GauthamM It is not necessary. Two is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/). It is not clear, at least to me, what you are trying to achieve. You may want to step back and ask yourself what the task is and provide more context to get a better help for your question.

If all you want is to print some output to console, you could do it like (assuming the method `findDifference` returns a string):

```
Stream.of(firstFileLog, second)
        .flatMap (Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Logs::getId,
                 Collectors.mapping(Logs::getTime,Collectors.toList())))
        .forEach((id,list) -> {
            System.out.println(id + "="
                                  + list
                                  + (list.size() <2 ? " - ignore": ", diff: "+ findDifference(list.get(0), list.get(1))));
        });
```

If you need the data for further processing there might be other approaches which are better suited for your reqierments. But it is hard to tell just by guessing, so you may want to include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the relevant classes and methods

Comment: You have accurately described my condition. After all, I'm just starting to learn the Stream API and I still don't understand well what is right and what is not. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `forEach` in your stream to do the required operation:
(Assume static import of `Collectors`

```java
Stream.of(firstFileLog, second)
      .flatMap (Collection::stream)
      .collect(groupingBy(Logs::getId, mapping(Logs::getTime, toList())))
      .entrySet()
      .forEach(entry -> {
           System.out.print(entry);
           List<Time> time = entry.getValue();
           if(time.size()==2) {
               System.out.print(findDifference(time.get(0), time.get(1)));               
           }
           System.out.println(); 
        };
      );
```